# How to check user during logging in and send them to different homepages

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am currently developing a Flutter App for a project with Firebase. It is the first time I am trying out flutter and I came to face the problem of sending users to different hompages based on what type they are. For example, an admin user will be sent to the admin homepage and a customer user to customer homepage etc.

My current login code does allow for me to login users but they all get sent to the customer's homepage since I don't really know how to implement a way to check what type of user during login. I differentiated users in cloud firestore by having different collections and a unique id; 'uid' for Users and 'aid' for Agencies.

I think I could use this code but I don't know how to put it together with my login code :

```
  Future<String> checkBothUserBasesForTheUser(String uid) async {
    DocumentSnapshot _userDoc =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
    if (_userDoc.exists) return 'users';
    DocumentSnapshot _agencyDoc =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('agencies').doc(uid).get();
    if (_agencyDoc.exists)
      return 'agencies';
    else
      return 'null';
  }
```

Current code for login:

```
    final loginButton = Material(
      elevation: 5,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      color: Color(0xFF003893),
      child: MaterialButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
          minWidth: 300,
          onPressed: () {
            signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
          },
          child: Text(
            "Login",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )),
       );
  
  void signIn(String email, String password) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      await _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((_userDoc) => {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                    msg: "Login Successful"),
                Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserMainpage())),
              })
          .catchError((e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          msg: "The email or password is invalid. Please check and try again.",
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

Is there any other way to check user type during logging in and send them to their respective homepages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [signInWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword) method returns an [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth#usercredential) structure, which contains an [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User) type. This User type seems to contain a property called [uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#uid), which you could pass to your `checkBothUserBasesForTheUser` function to check what kind of user it is.

###### Edited:

Then, I believe you should call your method with something like `checkBothUserBasesForTheUser(_userDoc.User.uid)` and based on the return value redirect to one page or another.

I have no way to test this code but something like this should give you an idea (and also note there might be some syntax errors):

```
void signIn(String email, String password) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      await _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((_userDoc) => {
              checkBothUserBasesForTheUser(_userDoc.User.uid)
              .then((result) => {
                  if(result == "users"){
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                        msg: "Login Successful"),
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserMainpage())),
                    }
                    else(result == "agency"){
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                        msg: "Login Successful"),
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AgencyMainpage())),
                    }
              })
            })
          .catchError((e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 3,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          msg: "The email or password is invalid. Please check and try again.",
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, how do I pass on the checkBothUserBasesForTheUser function? I put `checkBothUserBasesForTheUser('uid')` inside `.then((_userDoc)` but I don't know how to say if checkBothUserBasesForTheUser returns agencies, then redirect to agency homepage.

Comment: I believe you should use something like `checkBothUserBasesForTheUser(_userDoc.User.uid)` and based on the return value redirect to one page or another.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got a gist of it! However, I am facing another error so if you'd like to, check the code I wrote : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69736055/trying-to-login-different-users-and-error-ignoring-header-x-firebase-locale-be](here).

Comment: Edited my answer and added some code. Hopefully it points you to the right direction

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.